# Как правильно спарсить точную ссылку из чужого контента?

Tags: php, curl

Если вам непонятно что я пишу, прощу прощения за непонятные ошибки, я глухой.

При парсинге возникла странность, с помощью curl с прокси я парсил нужный текст с помощью рег.выр. это ссылка, текст спарсен и получил данные в .txt, но одно но - ссылка не одинаковая как в чужом контенте.

В моем txt выглядит так:

> get_file/13/526fc8d76ffdf6016a04cc3d53fe3da30**dcb4b4d0e**/366000/366201/366201_low.mp4

В чужом контенте:

> get_file/13/526fc8d76ffdf6016a04cc3d53fe3da30**e9458e40f**/366000/366201/366201_low.mp4

Можно ли каким то образом решить проблему?

Comment: Мне непонятно а чем разница в текстах.

Comment: ваш парсер работает верно, просто скорее всего в чужом контенте генерируется случайный хеш для ссылок

Comment: @programmer403 добрый вечер! ее можно каким то образом достать такой же хэш? если никак то можно имитировать заголовки ответа или бред?

Comment: @OberynMartell простой ответ никак. т.к. это уже другой вопрос и требует глубокого изучения поведения чужого контента, его анализ и составления конкретного алгоритма для этой задачи. Вопрос в том зачем вам точно такой же хеш? берите любой.

Comment: @programmer403 прикол в том что видео не воспроизводится( в точном хэше воспроизводится, не знаю как делать. Но спасибо за разьяснение.

Comment: так ссылка привязывается к ип адресу с которого ты его получил, при обращении через другой ип ссылка уже не будет работать. пропускай видосы через свой сервер

Comment: @Solo_777 спасибо, можно уточнить, что значит пропускать видосы через свой сервер? Имеете в виду собственный CDN?

Comment: @Oberyn Martell нет. я про ретрансляцию. вот готовое решение которое я юзал раньше https://pastebin.com/UL7Tp8gb

Comment: @Solo_777 немного сложновато вышло, но спасибо! Ваш код открывается "Скачать файл", это так должно быть, а как же в плеер встраивать?

Comment: @Oberyn Martell просто ссылку на эту страницу вставляете в плеер

Comment: @Solo_777 получилось, но к сожалению хэшированную ссылку не достанешь, придется вручную достать из исходного кода.